# I want to get into Operating Systems, where do I start?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, c, assembly

I have been doing web/app development for a few years, primarily involving high-level programming and stuff. However, I am interested in jumping into some low-level stuff and genuinely understanding how computers work.

There are a lot of resources online that I found myself being overwhelmed by all the choices. Generally people online say to learn C and Assembly first, but I found there are two architectures for Assembly, which one do I learn first? And what's after learning the language? Do I start doing sample projects? Or learn Linux? **I am looking for (any) advice for a beginner like me trying to develop an Operating System (to learn Computer Science).**

Ps: I'm using M1 Macbook with an ARM chip, not sure if this would affiliate with my choice of which Assembly to learn.

Comment: Developing a true operating system is a quite substantial project. OS's are commonly written with a small core in assembly and the rest in a compiled language such as C. But the assembly layer with a processor such as an ARM in a Mac platform requires much more than knowledge of the assembly, as it goes very deep in the system architecture.